# perl script to execute ssh command without using password

Tags: perl, ssh

I have a faceless account on a remote machine.i.e, i do not have to insert my password when doing a ssh.My question is that what should be my code if i do not have to use the password through the perl code.In the shown code its still asking for a password

```
 $cmd="cat /read.log";
 my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host, protocol => '1,2', debug => 1);
 $ssh->login($user, $pass);
 my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
 print $stdout, "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

While standard `ssh` checks for `id_rsa` and `id_dsa` in your `~/.ssh/` folder when using challenge-response authentication, [`Net::SSH::Perl`](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm) only looks in `$ENV{HOME}/.ssh/identity` for `RSA` and `$ENV{HOME}/.ssh/id_dsa` for `DSA`. I suspect this is the cause of the problem, and you can solve this by adding `identity_files` to the parameters passed to the `new` method.

Check your identities by executing `ls ~/.ssh/` and look for a file called `id_rsa`. Then simply set `identity_files` to include the appropriate paths.

Comment: K i do not have a file as id_rsa in ls ~/.ssh/  Can this not be hanled in the code itself..

Comment: I am almost afraid to ask... but do you have any id_ files in ~/.ssh?

Comment: They run some programs to do the passwordless login in  hte company .although i know that ssh keys  is the actuall way of implementing the passwordless login

Comment: In that case, you might be better off just using `ssh`, since it supports executing a command on the remote side. e.g. `ssh $server ls -l'` will return a listing of the login dir and exit.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the `identity_files` argument to `Net::SSH::Perl->new`. Check where your identity files are located and compare to the [module docs](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eturnstep/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm):

> identity_files
>
> A list of RSA/DSA identity files to be used in RSA/DSA authentication. The value of this argument should be a reference to an array of strings, each string identifying the location of an identity file. Each identity file will be tested against the server until the client finds one that authenticates successfully.
>
> If you don't provide this, RSA authentication defaults to using $ENV{HOME}/.ssh/identity, and DSA authentication defaults to $ENV{HOME}/.ssh/id_dsa.