# How to pass in password using Net::SSH in Perl?

Tags: perl, ssh

I am trying to avoid using Net::SSH::Perl library since there is some problems in installing the module using CPAN. Manual install seems too troublesome when I see that it depends on a long list of other Perl modules.

What I am trying to achieve is to log into the SSH with my username and password. Then I will need to run some commands in it and retrieve some files from the server using SSH.

I know how to pass the username, hostname and command using "ssh($username."@".$ip, $command) or die "SSH fails!";". However, I keep getting this error message:

```
ssh: connect to host XX.XX.XX.XXX port 22: Connection refused
```

where XX.XX.XX.XXX is the hostname or IP address of my computer and is in the subnet as the server that I am trying to get files from.

Does anyone knows how I can pass in the password to SSH or introduce me to good tutorials on Net::SSH? Most of the tutorials I found online are on Net::SSH::Perl and not for Net::SSH.

Comment: will it be useful for you. looks like similar discussion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766780/perl-script-to-execute-ssh-command-without-using-password

Comment: Hi. I need help on Net::SSH instead of Net::SSH::Perl as I can't install Net::SSH::Perl due to some problems with CPAN and manual install. The link you gave me is for Net::SSH::Perl.

Comment: Have you checked your distributions repository? Debian/Ubuntu has a lot of CPAN modules already built; for example `libnet-ssh-perl` and `libnet-ssh2-perl` are both available in UNIVERSE.

Comment: "Connection refused" means the client couldn't communicate with the server, not that the server rejected the credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see this FAQ section of the Net::SSH documentation?

> Q: How do you supply a password to connect with ssh within a perl
>   script using the Net::SSH module?
>
> A: You don't (at least not with this module). Use RSA or DSA keys. See
>   the quick help in the next section and the ssh-keygen(1) manpage.
>
> A #2: See Net::SSH::Expect instead.

The suggestion to try Net::SSH::Expect is a good one. It sounds, based on what you've said, that it fits your needs.
I have used Net::SSH::Expect quite a bit and I can attest to its simplicity if you're just looking to get something done quickly